# How to Export the Task Scheduler jobs using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to export the Task Scheduler jobs under Task Scheduler Library using Power shell.

But when i try to run the script it displays all the tasks which are in my machine, i don't want to export all those to a file,just need the tasks which are under Task Scheduler Library.

```
"ScheduledTasks"  
schtasks.exe /query /V /FO CSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

**Output**

```
HostName                             : XXXXXXXXX
TaskName                             : \Mozilla\Firefox Default Browser Agent 
                                       308046B0AF4A39CB
Next Run Time                        : 25-06-2021 18:03:40
Status                               : Ready
Logon Mode                           : Interactive only
Last Run Time                        : 24-06-2021 18:03:41
Last Result                          : 0
Author                               : Mozilla
Task To Run                          : C:\Program Files\Mozilla 
                                       Firefox\default-browser-agent.exe 
                                       do-task 308046B0AF4A39CB""
Start In                             : N/A
Comment                              : The Default Browser Agent task checks 
                                       when the default changes from Firefox 
                                       to another browser. If the change 
                                       happens under suspicious circumstances, 
                                       it will prompt users to change back to 
                                       Firefox no more than two times. This 
                                       task is installed automatic
Scheduled Task State                 : Enabled
Idle Time                            : Disabled
Power Management                     : 
Run As User                          : XXXX
Delete Task If Not Rescheduled       : Disabled
Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins : 00:35:00
Schedule                             : Scheduling data is not available in 
                                       this format.
Schedule Type                        : Daily 
Start Time                           : 18:03:40
Start Date                           : 21-06-2021
End Date                             : N/A
Days                                 : Every 1 day(s)
Months                               : N/A
Repeat: Every                        : Disabled
Repeat: Until: Time                  : Disabled
Repeat: Until: Duration              : Disabled
Repeat: Stop If Still Running        : Disabled
```

Comment: Normally you would do ```Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \``` but with `schtasks` I'm not sure how you can filter them.

Comment: Yes with just Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '\' i will get the details, but i want the entire output format as the above output

Comment: Right, then you would need to combine `Get-ScheduledTask` with `Get-ScheduledTaskInfo`.